# how to get direction of one place to another from latitudes and longitudes of both place?

Tags: java, math, geolocation, geometry, computational-geometry

how to get direction of one place to another from latitudes and longitudes of both place?
as for example if source is Peru or Mexico and destination is Alaska then result should be around clockwise 45 degree north = anticlockwise 45 degree west.

i actually need a function that may return the result taking both lat lon of both source and destination....

I am working in Android. But Here i just seek for the logic/calculation

Advance thanks

Comment: Try these links http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html and http://www.dougv.com/2009/07/13/calculating-the-bearing-and-compass-rose-direction-between-two-latitude-longitude-coordinates-in-php/

Comment: Can you please specify here on what platform you are working?

Comment: Wouldn't this be better on Math?

Comment: I would think [GIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) would be better than math. They could probably point to a good library for a given platform.

Comment: This is called a geodetic calculation. See http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/GeodesicCalculations for a nice overview, and as erickson suggests, see [http://gis.stackexchange.com] for detailed help.

Comment: Nice problem, I am trying to dio it!  Can I suppose that the earth is round?

Comment: nope @user983716 the shape of earth is what is its actual shape...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula will give you the initial heading to depart from the start point to the destination along a great circle:

```
θ = atan2(sin(Δlong)*cos(lat2), cos(lat1)*sin(lat2) − sin(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(Δlong))
```

Where `Δlong` is the overall change in longitude from start to destination and `lat1`, `lat2` are the latitude of the start/destination.

Note that the heading to the destination will change as you travel along the great circle, thus this heading would need to be continuously adjusted as you move toward the destination. Also note that you will need to map the angles returned by atan2() from +/- pi to 0-360°.

From: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html